# Incorrect Output from Loop in Code

Tags: java, methods, output

I have been struggling with this method I created for a assignment and it is driving me insane. I have an issue with my if/else statement but I cannot seem to find out what it is. This is the output I am receiving:

```
1: Lather and Rise.
2: Lather and rinse.
Done
2: Lather and Rise.
2: Lather and rinse.
Done
3: Lather and Rise.
2: Lather and rinse.
Done
```

I expect to see this:

```
1: Lather and rinse.
2: Lather and rinse.
Done.
```

What am I doing wrong to keep this from outputting properly? Any advice/help is appreciated! See Code Below:

```
public class ShampooMethod {

    public static void printShampooInstructions(int numCycles) {

        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ": Lather and Rise.");
            if (numCycles < 1) {
                System.out.println("Too few.");
            } else if (numCycles >= 4) {
                System.out.println("Too many");
            } else {
                System.out.println(numCycles + ": Lather and rinse.");
            }
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printShampooInstructions(2);

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code to make it possible to read.

Comment: Could it be the for loop that iterates 3 times which is wrapped around all your code?

Comment: this line printed first `System.out.println(i + ": Lather and Rise.");` so Rise always be the first to be printed

Comment: How can you expect to display one time if you loop 3 times ?

Comment: In the for loop put i <  numCycles

Comment: you might want to add `break;` after printing `done`to stop iterate

Answer (score 3):

6.4.2: Method with loop: Shampoo.

Write a method printShampooInstructions(), with int parameter numCycles, and void return type. If numCycles is less than 1, print "Too few.". If more than 4, print "Too many.". Else, print "N: Lather and rinse." numCycles times, where N is the cycle number, followed by "Done.". End with a newline. Example output with input 2:

1: Lather and rinse.

2: Lather and rinse.

Done.

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShampooMethod {

   /* Your solution goes here  */
   public static void printShampooInstructions(int numCycles) {
      if (numCycles < 1){
      System.out.println("Too few.");   
      }
      else if (numCycles > 4){
      System.out.println("Too many.");
      } 
      else {
         for(int i = 1; i <= numCycles; i++){
            System.out.println(i + ": Lather and rinse.");
         }
         System.out.println("Done.");
      }
   }

   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int userCycles;

      userCycles = scnr.nextInt();
      printShampooInstructions(userCycles);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

public class ShampooMethod {

```
public static void printShampooInstructions(int numCycles) {
    if (numCycles < 1) {
        System.out.println("Too few.");
    } else if (numCycles > 4) {
        System.out.println("Too many.");
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numCycles; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ": Lather and rinse.");
        }
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userCycles;

    userCycles = scnr.nextInt();
    printShampooInstructions(userCycles);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the comments below to see what caused a different output than you expected.

1. You were iterating one time to much
2. `System.out.println(i + ": Lather and Rise.");` will be displayed in every round of the loop because you don't *filter* it with a `if` or `else` or `else if`
3. Switched location for `System.out.println("Done");` after the loop - because you are done if the loop is done and you are at the end of your method.

---

```
public class ShampooMethod {

    public static void printShampooInstructions(int numCycles) {

        // i = 1 - i < (2+1=3) -> i will become 1 and than 2 -> done
        for (int i = 1; i < (numCycles+1); i++) {
            // this would be displayed every time you go throw the loop
            // System.out.println(i + ": Lather and Rise.");
            if (numCycles < 1) {
                System.out.println("Too few.");
            } else if (numCycles >= 4) {
                System.out.println("Too many");
            } else {
                System.out.println(i + ": Lather and rinse.");
            }
        }
        // Done goes here because only after the loop we are done
        System.out.println("Done");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printShampooInstructions(2);

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything in a loop gets executed the number of times the loop runs. In this case the loop executes 3 times because that is what you have set (int i = 1; i < 4; i++).
The lines "Lather and Rise" and "Done" get printed multiple times because they are also inside that loop.
Also you have no sentinal set up to prevent the last two "2: Lather and rinse." from getting printed. Set up a case for if where you don't print anything.

Answer (score 0):

The line: 'Lather and Rise' will be outputted every time the loop is run because it is not inside an if/else block. The same thing with 'Done'. Put this line outside of the for loop. Another thing to point out, instead of hardcoding 4, put i < numCycles. So in your case where you want to display 2 cycles of 'Lather and rinse', numCycles should be 2.

```
public static void printShampooInstructions(int numCycles) {

    for (int i = 0; i < numCycles; i++) {
        // System.out.println(i + ": Lather and Rise.");
        if (numCycles < 1) {
            System.out.println("Too few.");
        } else if (numCycles >= 4) {
            System.out.println("Too many");
        } else {
            System.out.println(numCycles + ": Lather and rinse.");
        }   
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (numCycles < 1) {
       System.out.println("Too few.");
      }
    else if (numCycles > 4) {
       System.out.println("Too many.");
      }
    else {
       for (i = 1; i <= numCycles; ++i) {
          System.out.println(i + ": Lather and rinse.");
         }
        System.out.println("Done.");
      }
```

I used an **if else** statement and on the tail of the statement at instance of **else**, I created a **for loop** that would print the **Lather and Rinse** statement followed by done and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Methods_ShampooMethod_ChallengeActivity {

        public static void printShampooInstructions(int numCycles) {
            

            if (numCycles < 1) {
                System.out.println("Too few.");
            }
            else if (numCycles > 4) {
                System.out.println("Too many.");
            }
            else {
                for (int i = 1; i <= numCycles; i++) {
                    System.out.println(i + ": Lather and rinse.");         
                }
            System.out.println("Done.");           
            }                
        }

        public static void main (String [] args) {
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
            int userCycles;
        
            System.out.print("Enter cycles: ");
            userCycles = scnr.nextInt();
        
            printShampooInstructions(userCycles);   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first `for` loop put this :
`for (int i = 1; i < numCycles; i++)`
instead of this:
`for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)`